# Какова этимология слов "вечность" и "век"?

Tags: этимология

Является ли слово "вечность" произошедшим от слова "век"?

Answer (score 1):

Да, именно так. Слово "век" может одначать не только "столетие", но и "жизнь". "Вековать" - "жить".